# How do you make Spring Boot default to a locale when a message key is missing?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, internationalization, spring-internationalization

How do I force Spring Boot to use a default locale when it can't find the message key in the user's given locale? I found this guide:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-internationalization

I have the following:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver lr = new AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver();
        lr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        return lr;
    }
```

I have `messages_es.properties`, `messages_en.properties` (and many more).

I have the key `oops-theme` in `messages_en.properties`, but it is absent from all the other `messages*.properties`.

I set my browser to `Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7`.

Yet, when I access a JSP page with the `oops-theme`, it gives the exception

> javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'oops-theme' for locale 'es_ES'.

The JSP contains

```
<spring:message code="oops-theme"/>
```

How do I use a default locale for looking up messages when Spring Boot can't find them in the given locale?

Spring Boot 1.5.21.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fill `messages.properties` with the messages for the fall-back text, e.g. in English.

Then don't write `messages_en.properties`, since the default messages are already in English.

Note that this is entirely independent of the `setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH)`, as that simply states which Locale to use if the Accept-Language header is missing.

*Example:* You can write `messages.properties` in German, if you want, then have a `messages_en.properties` for English, and `messages_es.properties` for Spanish. You can then have `setDefaultLocale(Locale.SPANISH)`, which means that if the browser doesn't specify a locale, you get Spanish, but for every message where a Spanish text hasn't been provided in `messages_es.properties`, you'd get the default German text from `messages.properties`.

You should read the javadoc of [`ResourceBundle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) and the [`PropertyResourceBundle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PropertyResourceBundle.html) subclass to learn how this all works.